How do I calculate the closed form of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-2}$
This is an exercise from Wade, the answer is given as; $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-2}=\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2},$$ but there is no help as to how to arrive at that answer. I have completed the first question of the exercise, but cannot make headway with the remaining 3. 
For the question above, I have only got so far as $$\frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)'.$$ Which does not simplify to the answer given...

You should include the question within the body of your post.

The original sum takes value $2$ when $x=0$, but you get to an expression which is infinite at $x=0$ so you've made a slip. You've not shown us the intermediate steps so it's impossible to say where you've gone astray.

Since, if $x\in(-1,1)$,$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k,$$you have that, on that interval$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1};$$in other words,$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}-1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-1}.$$That is,$$\frac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-1}.$$Therefore,$$\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-2}.$$

(and if $|x|\geq 1$ then the series does not converge)

In cases like this it helps to define a function $f(x)$ and see what you get playing around with it (maybe this is what you did):
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^{k-2}=2+\sum_{k=3}^\infty (k-1)x^{k-2}+\sum_{k=3}^\infty x^{k-2}$$
$$=2+\frac{x}{1-x}+\sum_{k=3}^\infty (k-1)x^{k-2}$$
Integrating this term by term (why is this allowed?) gives
$$F(x)=x-\ln(1-x)+\sum_{k=3}^\infty x^{k-1}=x-\ln(1-x)+\frac{x^2}{1-x}$$
We can ignore the $+C$ since we are quickly differentiating
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$$

If $|x| \lt 1,$ let the sum $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kx^{k-2}=S.$
On multiplying both sides by $x$ we get,
$$xS=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}(k-1)x^{k-2}$$
Subtracting the above two equations yields
$$(1-x)S=2+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}x^{k-2}$$
The latter term is the sum of an infinite geometric progression. Thus,
$$(1-x)S=2+\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{2-x}{1-x}$$
On dividing both sides by $x$,
$$S=\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$$
QED
